# Why I have to replug my mouse occasionally?

Tags: usb, mouse, hardware-failure

I've got two USB wired mouses (mice?): "Mad Catz R.A.T.7" and "Canyon CNL-MBMSO02". From time to time when I start my computer I find the latter mouse not working. But it starts working if I replug it. And it doesn't matter if I'm running Windows or Linux. Does anybody know what it has to do with?

**UPD** It was this way from the moment I bought the mouse.

**UPD** Even though I can't move the cursor, left and right buttons and the wheel are working.

**UPD** Well, today my mouse stopped working again. After I was unable to bring my computer back from sleep. Though, I highly doubt my mouse stops working every time this happens. Be that as it may, I've got these events in "Custom Views\Administrative Events" log starting from reboot:

```
Warning 10/29/2013 12:39:48 PM  DNS Client Events   1014    (1014)
Name resolution for the name tracker.mightynova.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.

Error   10/29/2013 12:38:35 PM  PrintService    370 Verifying or regenerating a print driver package
The print spooler failed to regenerate the printer driver information for driver Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver for environment Windows NT x86. Win32 system error code 1633 (0x661). This can occur after an operating system upgrade or because of data loss on the hard drive.

Error   10/29/2013 12:38:35 PM  PrintService    215 Installing a printer driver
Installing printer driver Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver failed, error code 0x0, HRESULT 0x80070661. See the event user data for context information.

Error   10/29/2013 12:38:35 PM  PrintService    215 Installing a printer driver
Installing printer driver Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver failed, error code 0x661, HRESULT 0x80070661. See the event user data for context information.

Error   10/29/2013 12:38:35 PM  PrintService    215 Installing a printer driver
Installing printer driver Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver failed, error code 0x661, HRESULT 0x80070661. See the event user data for context information.

Error   10/29/2013 12:38:35 PM  PrintService    215 Installing a printer driver
Installing printer driver - failed, error code 0xBC8, HRESULT 0x80070BC8. See the event user data for context information.

Error   10/29/2013 12:37:23 PM  Service Control Manager 7024    None
The VMware Workstation Server service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
%%4294967295

Error   10/29/2013 12:37:13 PM  EventLog    6008    None
The previous system shutdown at 11:05:08 AM on ‎10/‎29/‎2013 was unexpected.

Error   10/29/2013 12:37:16 PM  Eventlog    1101    Event processing
Audit events have been dropped by the transport.  0

Critical    10/29/2013 12:37:07 PM  Kernel-Power    41  (63)
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

The most suspicious events to me are the ones concerning printer. Because I've got no printer.

Comment: Have you check the event log to see if there are any messages related to this? When it happens, is there an indication in device manager?

Comment: Maybe meeses. Also the error logs arn't related I suspect. Just to rule out the obvious - are these mice connected directly to a USB port or to a hub? Front or rear connectors? I'm wondering if somehow the mouse isn't getting enough power at times.

Comment: Come to think of it, it is connected using 2 meter USB to USB cable, connected to the rear panel of computer case. You think it might be the reason? Gotta try to connect it directly to the front panel...

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Well, connecting directly to the front panel doesn't help.

Comment: "2 meter USB to USB cable" that definately may be an issue. Not all USB cables are made the same - what happens when you connect directly to the rear?

Comment: Connecting directly to the rear panel doesn't solve the problem, but I discovered that even though I can't move the cursor, left and right buttons and the wheel are working. Before I made my judgements on inability to move the cursor alone.